My favourite author!
Preface
These have been pretty fun. I thought I'd throw another one out there. This is more of a softball than my other literature connect wall, but still a toughie if you don't have the knowledge!
Simple rules; it's a standard connect wall, so you'll need the four categories. To win, you'll also need to tell me the overarching theme, or more specifically; who's my favourite author?
Wall











SOLAR
VULCAN
DOCTOR
COSMIC


MAN
HIGH
GAME
FRIENDS


DIVINE
VAST
FLOW
CONFESSIONS


WORLD
BUILD
ARCHER
TEETH




I'm pretty sure your favorite author is

 Philip K. Dick

since you love words that appear in

 the titles of his novels. (Though I suspect some of that love should transfer to his editors, since authors often don't get to pick titles.)

I'm not sure about the categories though. Some words are ambiguous and I haven't found a satisfying way to either disambiguate them or make them a category of their own. I had to use a lathe to make them fit (and if you don't get it, absolutely do read the book I mention at the end of my answer).
There is an apparent grouping if you sort

 by publication date

assuming that

 a word that appears in multiple titles counts for the first novel whose title uses that word.

Then the categories are

 for each decade of publication.

The full list:

 • Solar Lottery (1954)
 • The World Jones Made (1956) or Counter-Clock World (1967)
 • The Man Who Japed (1956) or The Man in the High Castle (1962) or The Man Whose Teeth Were All Exactly Alike (1984 (posthumous))
 • The Cosmic Puppets (1957)

 • Vulcan's Hammer (1960)
 • Doctor Futurity (1960)
 • The Man in the High Castle (1962)
 • The Game-Players of Titan (1963)

 • Our Friends from Frolix 8 (1970)
 • We Can Build You (1972)
 • Flow My Tears, the Policeman Said (1974)
 • Confessions of a Crap Artist (1975)

 • Vast from VALIS (1981)
 • The Divine Invasion (1981)
 • The Transmigration of Timothy Archer (1982)
 • The Man Whose Teeth Were All Exactly Alike (1984 (posthumous))

As an aside,

 I think his short stories are generally stronger than his novels. Mind you, I'm far more drawn to his inventive period than his later mysticism.

Finally, let me drop a word for what could be argued to be the best

 PKD novel: The Lathe of Heaven – featuring typical Dickian themes such as the ambiguous nature of reality, the way to hell being paved by the best intentions, mental health, a strong local attachment to the US West Coast and a record store. By Ursula K. LeGuin.


A winner on both counts! Yes, the categories are decades!

Also, I think I agree with you in the general case. His short stories are the best, and I'm not so into the mystic stuff. A Scanner Darkly is still probably my favourite book ever though.
